# every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

When i try to run this sql query
i get the following error: "every derived table must have its own alias"

sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM `evenement` 
LEFT JOIN `evenementontvanger` ON `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent` = `evenement`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `Werknemer`,
                      GROUP_CONCAT(`Initialen`) AS `Initials`
                 FROM `Werknemer` )  
WHERE `idEvent`=`evenement`.`id` AND `evenementontvanger`.`idWerknemer`=20
```

I Cant make it run.
Can someone help me plz
because it does run without the group concat

Comment: Does left join works without ON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `evenement` LEFT JOIN `evenementontvanger` 
ON `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent` = `evenement`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `Werknemer`,
                  GROUP_CONCAT(`Initialen`) AS `Initials`
           FROM `Werknemer` ) a --<-missing alias here
on sometablename.somecolumnname = a.somecolumnname
WHERE evenementontvanger.idEvent =evenement.id
AND `evenementontvanger`.`idWerknemer`=20
```

Comment: I get an sql error on line 8 near 'WHERE `idEvent`=`evenement`.`id` AND `evenementontvanger`.`idWerknemer`=20

Comment: you need to specify the on clause... `on  sometablename.somecolumnname = a.somecolumnname `

Comment: also the where add the table that belongs to `idEvent` in the where like `WHERE evenementontvanger.idEvent =evenement.id`

Comment: When i do it like this: ON `evenementontvanger`.`idWerknemer` = a.`idWerknemer` i get an error: Unknown column 'a.idWerknemer' in 'on clause'

Comment: yes, that's correct,  the `a` table has 2 columns only: `Werknemer` and `Initials` - you have to join on one of these or add something else in the derived table to join on

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an alias for your inline select, something like this:

```
(SELECT `Werknemer`,
                  GROUP_CONCAT(`Initialen`) AS `Initials`
             FROM `Werknemer` ) AS [tableName]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the alias:

```
SELECT *
FROM `evenement` LEFT JOIN
     `evenementontvanger
      ON `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent` = `evenement`.`id` LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT `Werknemer`, GROUP_CONCAT(`Initialen`) AS `Initials`
       FROM `Werknemer`
      )  w
---------^
      on w.`idEvent` = `evenement`.`id` 
WHERE `evenementontvanger`.`idWerknemer` = 20;
```

Note I added an `on` clause to the `join`.  Your whole query would look better with table aliases for all the tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM `evenement` e LEFT JOIN
     `evenementontvanger eov
      ON eov.`idEvent` = e.`id` LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT `Werknemer`, GROUP_CONCAT(`Initialen`) AS `Initials`
       FROM `Werknemer` w
      )  w
---------^
      on w.`idEvent` = e.`id` 
WHERE eov.`idWerknemer` = 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
SELECT * 
FROM `evenement` LEFT JOIN `evenementontvanger` 
ON `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent` = `evenement`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `Werknemer`,
                  GROUP_CONCAT(`Initialen`) AS `Initials`
           FROM `Werknemer` ) AS subQuery
ON subQuery.XYZ = ...
WHERE `idEvent`=`evenement`.`id` 
AND `evenementontvanger`.`idWerknemer`=20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `Werknemer`,
                  GROUP_CONCAT(`Initialen`) AS `Initials`
           FROM `Werknemer`
```

This select statement returns something. You try to join it with other tabels, for that you need to give this statement a name and give the colomn so that the sql knows how to join them. IT should look something like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `evenement` LEFT JOIN `evenementontvanger` 
ON `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent` = `evenement`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `Werknemer`,
                  GROUP_CONCAT(`Initialen`) AS `Initials`
           FROM `Werknemer` )   as GIVE_AN_NAME on give_an_name.column = 'evenement'.column
WHERE `idEvent`=`evenement`.`id` 
AND `evenementontvanger`.`idWerknemer`=20
```